# String was not recognized as a valid Boolean checkboxes on a view

Tags: c#, razor

I have went through many previous posts of this error. I have a dynamic list of items being displayed in a table and each row has a checkbox that I can check to delete that row or not on the post.  Neither my boss or myself can figure out why we are getting this error on this line.  I have commented out all the code in the post action result so the same data is coming into the view each time.

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("LogsToDelete[" + i + "]", false, new { @value = log.ID, @class = "checkbox" })</td>
```

I am incrementing "i" during each loop to get a unique string name for each checkbox.  For some reason it doesn't like this.  If I change "i" to a 4 or a 5 or(what ever number) the page reloads fine.  But with the "i" it throws this error.  I even tried building that portion before this line and then just sticking my temp variable in it but I still get the same error string-> bool error.

```
string temp = "LogsToDelete[" + i.ToString() + "]";
```

Comment: Try LogsToDelete[<text>i</text>]

Comment: The key to solve this problem is show the error you have when assigning with index. And what type that `LogsToDelete` collection has (I assumed `IEnumerable`/`List` of something)?

Comment: NicoRiff; thanks for your response.  I don't want 'i' to be static because that is what makes each checkbox dynamically have a new name.

Comment: tetsuya, thanks for the response.  Here is the defn:  public List<string> LogsToDelete { get; set; }

Comment: Tetsuys:  It is this list that I parse through to delete the required records; but this functionality works perfect.  It is when it returns back that I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LogsToDelete[i].Checked, new { @class = "checkbox" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LogsToDelete[i].LogID)

I ended up making a class that held two item; an int for the ID of the item to delete, and a bool to store the .checked value of the checkbox.  Before the page loads I make a list of objects of my "logsToDelete".  Then use this to determine which logs to delete in the post. 
 thanks guys.